# Overfull \hbox caused by em-dash

Tags: line-breaking, punctuation, warnings

There is one problem that currently seems insolvable to me. I am typesetting a book in Russian language and I noticed that, in some cases, an overfull box appears which cannot be solved via manual `\hyphenation` or `\linebreak` or even `\emergencystretch`, because an em-dash is causing it. Due to the typesetting rules, the em-dash MUST stay at the end of the line if the line is about to break at this point, which is why moving it to the beginning of the next line cannot be considered.

I tried applying `microtype`, but it seems not being able to condense the em-dash ONLY in case it is positioned at the end of the line AND is causing an overfull. Or to condense it at all, to be honest. If I re-define the width of the em-dash-symbol, the same problem will occur at other positions in the book.

Changing the width of the text body didn't bring the desired effect either, because same situation came up as described above.

Here comes the MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,russian,open=any]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=14.2cm, paperheight=20.4cm, top=1cm, bottom=1.3cm, twoside, inner=1.0cm, outer=1.2cm, bindingoffset=0.5cm, footskip=0.65cm, headsep=0cm, headheight=0cm, voffset=0pt, hoffset=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[kerning=true, tracking=true, spacing=true, selected=true, babel=true, stretch=10, shrink=10]{microtype}

\deffootnote[1.5em]{0.5em}{0em}{
\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}

\setlength{\parindent}{1.25em}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{1pt}

\frenchspacing 
\righthyphenmin=2 

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}

\clubpenalty=10000 
\widowpenalty=10000
\flushbottom 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[EC,OC]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Когда его вопль, отражаясь испуганной белкой от пустых котлов и голых стен, замер, завязнув в тягучей темноте, снова воцарилась тишина, нарушить которую было не в силах даже потрескивание дров в одиноком камине. Конечно, надо было бы пойти бросить в него ещё несколько поленьев, но за это время эти подонки смогут улизнуть или спрятаться получше!..

--- Да. Его так зовут. Забавно, правда? Царство Костей. Костей~--- правитель Царства Костей. 

Агафон насупился, поколебался несколько секунд между <<Именно секрет>> и <<А тебе зачем?>>, но вздохнул подавленно, махнул рукой и признался.

--- В Царство Костей,~--- с надеждой вскинул на него глаза Иван~--- уж не вспомнит ли дед ещё что-нибудь полезное?

--- Ну хорошо. А как насчёт неразговаривания с набитым ртом?~--- не сдавался Костей.

\end{document}
```

Oh, and I'm using TeXstudio 2.5.2.

If you take a closer look at the screenshot you'll see that sometimes even the hyphenation symbol is protruding into the margin, which also causes an overfull hbox:

[image]

I'd like to know how to handle these overfull boxes. Is there a way to narrow those symbols depending on their position in text or something like this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I don't get overfull boxes if I use microtype with the default settings `\usepackage{microtype}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So did I first, and when it didn't help, I turned to the package documentation and Internet to see what else could be adjusted. Microtype doesn't produce an error while working with cyrillic cmr letters, but also seems not to do much, sadly.

Comment: Hm. You mean it doesn't work if you remove the microtype options in your example above? Then show the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I removed all the options from the Example.tex, and with these selected sentences, it worked. Then I applied same changes for the whole document and I still found some cases with em-dashes where it didn't help. The log-file is here - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33041425/Example.log  Oh, and I added such sentence to the Example-file.

Comment: I would not use `longword~--- longword`. I would use `longword---longword` or `longword --- longword`. Furthermore, in the first case, if you found that `TeX` is given problems, you can use `\-` for each word width problems to make it hyphenate properly, `long\-word---long\-word`. In the second, you can use `\hyphenation{long-word}` in the preamble and keep `longword --- \longword` in the text.

Comment: @cacamailg According to the typesetting rules for Russian books, which may well be different from German or English or whatever other, you must not separate em-dash and preceeding word, hence the "~"-sign on the left. I already apply manual hyphenation where necessary/possible, but sometimes, a word cannot be hyphenated at all (or Latex doesn't do it if stretching the sentence that is left would result in too much whitespace), plus em-dash following - there you have it... My problem is slightly different from what you are suggesting, but nonetheless thanks for participating.

Comment: And if you increase penalities? Let's say `\hyphenpenalty=1000`, `\exhyphenpenalty=1000`, `\hbadness=10000`, `\vbadness=10000` as you already have others defined. Does it help?

Comment: @cacamailg Will try...

Comment: @cacamailg No, it didn't help with remaining cases which were left after removing microtype options as Ulrike Fischer suggested, even made it worse.

Comment: Well. You can use `\sloppy` in the preamble of your document. But you must check how the document looks. It makes TeX to be more relaxed. Additionally you can can use something like `\newcomand*{\dword}{\mbox{#1 ---}}` in the preamble, and each time you need a word and a dash next, write `\dword{word}`, it will appear as `word ---`.

Comment: @cacamailg I wouldn't use `\newcommand*{\dword}{\mbox{#1 ---}}` - if I'm not mistaken the space between the word and the em-dash won't shrink or stretch any more when you place it in an `\mbox` which would cause uneven interword spacing.

Comment: It may be really newbie-style, but I first tried to suggest Latex where to hyphenate the word preceding the em-dash, and if Latex would not apply the hyphenation by itself, I forced it by enclosing the last syllable together with the em-dash and the following word in \mbox, like `syllab\-\mbox{le~--- syllable}` (so the box WILL move to the next line). This way, I could exterminate all overfull \hbox. BUT. If I will have to change the page layout, like reduce margins, this may cause unwanted problems with linebreaks. I will have to search for my \mbox-es manually after each adjustment.

Comment: @Aaliyah »BUT. If I will have to change the page layout« - That's why such manual adjustments should be made as the last thing after the whole document is ready and not going to change any more. It doesn't make much sense earlier, any way: if the text or layout still may change the overfull boxes might still go away or appear at different places.

Comment: @cgnieder I don't know the internals of LaTeX to typeset the em-dash. My suggestion was just to guarantee, that if necessary it will move to the next line. I know it is not the best thing.

Comment: @cacamailg But that's already ensured with `~`. Placing it in `\mbox{}` will also prevent hyphenation (the whole box will be moved to the next line). It would make it even harder to find a suitable breakpoint.

Comment: @Aaliyah: You can try to loosen the settings in the paragraphs affected. http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=overfull. I personally wouldn't care if there is 1pt overfull, that's so small that it isn't seen anyway.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I guess, I will have to perform all the adjustments after the whole book is put together, for it seems that there is no way to automatize this. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Aaliyah -- if a smaller (unbreakable) space before the em-dash is acceptable, you could use the thin space (`\,`) instead of `~`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It actually did help by reducing some of the remaining overfull hboxes to a half without particularly standing out as having been reduced. Thank you! But again, this will be one of the manual adjustments I'll have to do at the end of the typesetting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the space before and after the dash have more flexibility than a normal wrod space. The setting here leaves just one overfull box, not caused by the dash but just that TeX could not find a good place to break the line, I added one `\-` to add an extra hyphenation option which might not be appropriate place as I can not read the script unfortunately. It is in any case not connected with the spacing around `---`

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,russian,open=any]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=14.2cm, paperheight=20.4cm, top=1cm, bottom=1.3cm, twoside, inner=1.0cm, outer=1.2cm, bindingoffset=0.5cm, footskip=0.65cm, headsep=0cm, headheight=0cm, voffset=0pt, hoffset=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[kerning=true, tracking=true, spacing=true, selected=true, babel=true, stretch=10, shrink=10]{microtype}

\deffootnote[1.5em]{0.5em}{0em}{
\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}

\setlength{\parindent}{1.25em}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{1pt}

\frenchspacing 
\righthyphenmin=2 

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}

\clubpenalty=10000 
\widowpenalty=10000
\flushbottom 
\def\mydash{\ifhmode\nobreak\hspace{.33em plus .1em minus .25em}\fi---\hspace{ .33em plus .1em minus .25em}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[EC,OC]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Когда его вопль, отражаясь испуганной белкой от пустых котлов и голых стен, замер, завязнув в тягучей темноте, снова воцарилась тишина, нарушить которую было не в силах даже потрескивание дров в одиноком камине. Конечно, надо было бы пойти бросить в него ещё несколько поленьев, но за это время эти подонки смогут улизнуть или спрятаться получше!..

\mydash Да. Его так зовут. Забавно, правда? Царство Костей. Костей\mydash правитель Царства Костей. 

Агафон насупился, поколебался несколько секунд между <<Име\-нно секрет>> и <<А тебе зачем?>>, но вздохнул подавленно, махнул рукой и признался.

\mydash В Царство Костей,\mydash с надеждой вскинул на него глаза Иван\mydash уж не вспомнит ли дед ещё что-нибудь полезное?

\mydash Ну хорошо. А как насчёт неразговаривания с набитым ртом?\mydash не сдавался Костей.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is IT, thank you so much! BTW, is the "normal" space amount of 0.33em an approximation or some standard for space width? The `\-` you added is, unfortunately, at the spot where this word cannot be broken, but I still can insert some smaller spaces instead or normal ones along the text line, maybe this will save me the space needed to place one additional letter without Overfull.